# MVC Kendo Grid Custom Filter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Basically, I am looking for the MVC version of this demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

Here is what I currently have:

```
.Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.ID)
                .Hidden();
            columns.Bound(e => e.SearchFunctionCode)
                .Hidden();
            columns.Bound(e => e.SearchFunctionDesc)                
                .Title("Search Function")
                .Filterable( *** WHAT GOES HERE? *** )
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
                .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" });
```

Do I still reference the javascript, or is there another approach?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SearchFunctionFilter(element) {
        element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: searchfunctions(),
            optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes we need to define specified filter functions in javascript like below.

```
.Columns(columns => {
        columns.Template(@<text>@item.FirstName  @item.LastName</text>)
                .ClientTemplate("#=FirstName# #=LastName#")
                .Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(e => e.City)
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("cityFilter"))
                .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Title)
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("titleFilter"))
                .Width(350);   
    })    
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
            ))
        )   
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Read", "Grid"))
     )
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function cityFilter(element) {
        element.kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Cities")"
                }
            },
            optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
        });
    }

    function titleFilter(element) {
        element.kendoAutoComplete({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Titles")"
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

see this

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization

Comment: You moved the filter to the whole grid.  I'm looking to make one specific column filterable.  And I would like to limit the column options (when editing/adding) to the elements available in the filter.  I'm still researching, but I think I need to use the UIHint with a new editor template, and a Html.DropDownListFor

Comment: I think you are correct - they don't show how the UI for the dropdown works in their example. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Malkan's answer should work.  All you need to do is have a separate filter on each column.  just replace the column "filterable" with whatever you like like this:

```
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
        ))
    )
```